# How to set country code in textview to select country name in spinner?

Tags: android

This is main XML:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="29dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countrycode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText2" />
```

This is my Java code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    TextView textview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countrycode);

        // Spinner element
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        // Spinner click listener
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        String[] countryname = {"India", "America", "Japan", "Austrailia", "Canada" };

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countryname);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


//        // Showing selected spinner item
       Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

This is my code. How can I set country code in TextView to select country name in Spinner? I want to use this code because its easy to understand for me and it's working but I can't do what I want.

I want that if I select India in Spinner then I get India ISD code (+91) is TextView.

Comment: You want your Spinner to display country name based on which country code you typed in TextView?

Comment: It is working but I can't do what I want? Then it is not working for you.
As far as I could understand your question you want to select country from a spinner and upon selecting country, textView gets updated with its country code right? 
then what is the issue in it? seems candid and easily solvable.

Answer (score 0):

Set a TextWatcher for your TextView:

`textview.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher());` and implement `onTextChange()` method to get the typed country code from user, then put in a swich/case to determine which country name should me selected.

Answer (score 0):

Use Hashtable.

```
class MainActivity {

....
    Hashtable countryCodes<String, String>;
    TextView textViewCountryCode;
....

    onCreate(....){
        ....
        textViewCountryCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countrycode);
        countryCodes = new Hashtable<>();
        countryCodes.put("India", "+91");
        ....

    }
....
    onItemSelected(....){
        ....
        String countryCode = countryCodes.get(item);
        textViewCountryCode.setText(countryCode);
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What I understood is you want the  answer in the code provided by you . So what you can do is take one more array of Country code and On Spinner onSelected method set the selected position to the text view but make sure to keep the Country name and country code index same .Or i would recommend do it using HashMap for the same.

// add this below before oncreate
 TextView textview;
        String[] countrycode = {"+91", "+1", "+81", "+61", "+1" };

and in onItemSelected() method do this

textview.setText(countrycode[position]);